# accessing a static map from a static member function - segmentation fault - C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement factory pattern by registering the function  pointers of the derived class to the factory in a static map(member of the factory)and creating objects by looking up the map. But I am getting a segmentation fault in doing this.

Code Snippet:

factory.cpp

```
typedef Shape* (*Funcptr)();

std::map<int,Funcptr> Factory::funcmap;

int Factory::registerCreator(int ShapeID, Shape *(*CFuncptr)()) {
    Factory::funcmap[ShapeID] = CFuncptr;
return 1;
} 

Shape* Factory::CreateObject(int ShapeID) {
    std::map<int,Funcptr>::iterator iter;
    iter = funcmap.find(ShapeID);
    if(iter != funcmap.end()){
        return iter->second();
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

factory.h

```
class Factory {
public:
    Factory();
    virtual ~Factory();
    static int registerCreator(int, Shape *(*CFuncptr)());
    Shape* CreateObject(int);
private:
    static  std::map<int,Funcptr> funcmap;
};
```

Square.cpp

```
static Shape *SquareCreator() { 
    return new Square; 
}
static int SquareAutoRegHook = Factory::registerCreator(1,SquareCreator);
```

On creating the object for Factory in the main file a segmentation fault occurs. 
Can you please suggest if I am doing something wrong. I am using CppUTest for TDD and not sure how to debug this.

Comment: Show the typedef for `Funcptr`. Can you rewrite your code so it uses the typedef everywhere (and test)? Also, why is `SquareCreator()` declared `static`?

Comment: Unrelatedly, I'm not even sure now if function pointers are covariantly compatible. I just tried to test this myself, and I just got a flat-out "cannot convert" error.

Comment: @KerrekSB: sorry I did not understand what is "covariantly compatible". I am able to compile the code. Actually I am looking to create a factory without if else statements so that it does not violate OCP. So I was trying to use function pointers. Also I dont want to create all the derived class objects and register it with the map. It will be helpful, If you can suggest me some other neat way of doing it.

Comment: I mean that if you have `class A; class B : public A;`, then the question is if `B* (*)()` is convertible to `A* (*)()`. I thought so, but my compiler tells me it's an error...

Comment: Oh ok I get it now but for me it is not throwing any error. I am using gcc 4.5.3. Can you provide any example implementation link/ or some concept of factory that creates objects as I mentioned above?

Comment: Ah, wait: You're fine because your `SquareCreator` returns a `Shape*`, not a `SquareShape*`. That's OK then. I had somehow assumed for a moment that your creator functions would return the most derived pointer type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no guarantee about the order of creation of static objects that are defined in different translations uints* so you have a 50/50 shot as to which would happen first, the initializtion of `Factory::funcmap` or `Factory::registerCreator(1,SquareCreator)` and Undefined Behavior Russian Roulette is not a good game to play.

A common approach to deal with this, and one that described in Item 4 of [the third edition of Scott Meyer's Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) is to use local static objects instead of global static objects.  In this case it means changing `Factory` to look like this:

```
class Factory { 
public: 
    Factory(); 
    virtual ~Factory(); 
    static int registerCreator(int, Shape *(*CFuncptr)()); 
    Shape* CreateObject(int); 
private: 
    static std::map<int,Funcptr> & GetFactoryMap() {
        static std::map<int,Funcptr> funcmap;
        return funcmap;
    } 
};
```

and changing `Factory::registerCreator` to this:

```
int Factory::registerCreator(int ShapeID, Shape *(*CFuncptr)()) {   
    GetFactoryMap()[ShapeID] = CFuncptr;   
    return 1;   
}
```

This way funcmap will be initialized the first time registerCreator is called and will never be used uninitialized.

*Or, roughly speaking, different .cpp files if you are not familar with the term translation unit

Comment: I have tried this trick and I've had the problem that with some compilers multiple funcmaps are being created if you use the factory across different statically linked libraries and executables. Now I have a funcmap for each library or executable, but only if it's compiled on certain systems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [static initialization order fiasco](http://libcw.sourceforge.net/global/global.html). It seems that at the time when `SquareAutoRegHook` is initialized, the `funcmap` has not been created yet.

Comment: How to ensure the order of initialization or any other neat way of doing it?

Comment: That looks about right. It's also strange that `SquareCreator()` has internal linkage if a pointer to it is required globally.

Comment: @Saaras - you cannot ensure order of initialization of static objects, so use initialization routines that will do the setup for you when called from `main`. Once `main` starts you can rely on all the static variables to be initialized (in an undefined order).